# creating and signing a custom file type

Tags: c#, code-signing, file-type

I believe this is going to be a big question but I searched the web for at least an hour for an answer and I hope here I'll get the answer.
So the thing is I want to create my own file extension that will essentially be a binary file that my program will obviously will know how to interpret.
I know how to create a binary file and read from it, I understood that all I need is to change the extension and check it before I start reading the file.

The question is even if I create my own extension and check for it before start reading, I can't know that the file was really created by my application, someone could just change the extension and my application won't get the data it needs (of course I'll put everything in a try and catch so the application won't crush).

Is there a way to sign a binary file before opening it so people that get the file can know that my application created that file and not something that someone changed to look like my file type?

It's more of an idea I have so I don't have any code to show or any example other than this scenario.
All I need is something that people will know came from me and not something that every other person can generate on his own (not talking about programmers, I'm talking about regular people).

If you know anything about this subject please direct me to the answer or if you know post it here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would create a special sequence at the beginning of the file (a file header)

Comment: Again this will tell the people using it if the file is right only after they try to open it. I want them to know before they even begin to download the file from a website or something like that.

Answer (score 1):

One way could be to encrypt the contents of the file, then have your application decrypt it.

Anyone opening the file in your application would immediately know if that application generated it.

Comment: ok how do you encrypt a file?  and people will know only after trying to use the file with the application. I want them to know when let's say they download the file that it was created with my application and not with something else.

Comment: I was thinking of encrypting the contents of the file, but as you responded, that doesn't seem to be the solution.

Where will these people be downloading the file from?  If they're downloading the file from your site, they shouldn't have anything to worry about.  If they're downloading from a site outside of your control, I don't think it's possible to know that file is legitimate without at least having downloaded it.

Comment: yeah thought so, I don't know yet how they'll get the file (since I don't yet have any website) I thought about people sending the files to their friends. and I wanted to know how I can show that it was created by my application and not by someone else changing it to my extension. maybe something like digital signing it or something, I don't know anything about signing code or files this is why I asked.

Comment: I believe even with the 'digital signatures' that you're speaking of involves the exchange of public/private keys.  So it still wouldn't be possible to make that kind verification without at least some information exchanged.